# PHPMYADMIN ,,Error in Processing Request Error code: 200 Error text: OK

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Using PhpMyAdmin with PHP and MySQL stack in Ubuntu I encounter the problem:

> 1146 – Table ‘phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs’ doesn’t exist

TO solve this I added:

```
$ Cfg [‘Servers’] [$ i] [‘table_uiprefs’] = ‘pma_table_uiprefs';
```

Changed to:

```
$ cfg [‘Servers’] [$ i] [‘pma__table_uiprefs’] = ‘pma__table_uiprefs';
```

in  **config.inc.php** file after that I've got the problem like:

> Error in Processing Request
>
> Error code: 200
>
> Error text: OK

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you please post code from config.inc.php? have you checked database and db table exists?

Comment: config.inc.php have only this code
$ Cfg [‘Servers’] [$ i] [‘table_uiprefs’] = ‘pma_table_uiprefs';

Changed to: $ cfg [‘Servers’] [$ i] [‘pma__table_uiprefs’] = ‘pma__table_uiprefs';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like your config has been modified put this in /var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and also change password below if you set something else blank

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][1]['user'] = 'root'; //edit this line
$cfg['Servers'][1]['password'] = 'XXXX'; // your password
```

and comment this line for now

```
//$ cfg [‘Servers’] [$ i] [‘pma__table_uiprefs’] = ‘pma__table_uiprefs';
```

Comment: Adding this solves the error but  It don't allow me to perform any operation .

Comment: what errors are you getting? is it something related to permission? not sure try restart apache

Comment: Ya , I have set password set and AllowNoPassword is true.

Comment: Restarting still not worked , it still not allowing me to perform operation inside localhost/phpmyadmin.

Comment: do you get message "operation not permitted"? can you please paste message!!!  try change permission /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Comment: I did not got any message like that but I can not click and select the database and change table or neither can add new table but when I take  it to new tab with right click new tab I can drop Table.

Comment: there are so many free tools available on ubuntu for using mysql  and to get problem details you are facing now.  use other than phpmyadmin and post error details here

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I did all the tutorials I found, and it didn't work for me, I use XAMPP, but at the end of watching so many videos, uninstalling program 1 and again and again, it occurred to me to open xampp from another browser and no longer it gave me the error, so I started deleting all the Cookies from my Chrome browser and it started working again. that worked for me.