# Phpmyadmin error 200 when loading table structure

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

we have been using phpmyadmin for about 10 years, but since 3-4 days ago, when I click on a table and then on the Structure menu, PMA gives me this error in a red popup:

> Error in Processing Request Error code: 200 Error text: OK
>
> MySQL version is 4.5.1 PHP version is: 5.5.30 Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 PHP
>   extension: mysqli Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) Server version:
>   5.1.73-community - MySQL Community Server (GPL) Server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx via TCP/IP

I have searched the other questions, but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Code 200 usually is not bad :), Mysql 4.5.1 serious ? Have you made any changes to your system ? Its not normal that it has worked for 10 years and it just stopped..

Comment: Have you changed your error settings in PHP or your PHPMyAdmin settings  to force feedback of non errors such as notices?

Comment: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/58263

Comment: Maybe this wil help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815351/phpmyadmin-error-in-processing-request-error-code-200-error-text-ok

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? Could it possibly the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971120/phpmyadmin-error-code-200-when-load-table-structure ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers.
It was the language file that was the cause of the error. The error doesn't show anymore if i use other language than italian.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: same error 200 here when opening Structure view, changing from Italian language to English fixed it, there should be some issues in the language files, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: tracking for this bug is [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11705)