# phpmyadmin Error code: 200 when load table structure

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I load a table's structure, PMA gives me this error in a red popup:

> Error in Processing Request Error code: 200 Error text: OK

PhpMyAdmin version: 4.5.2

Windows 10
Apache 2.4.17 (Win32) 
PHP 5.6.14
MySQL Community Server 5.7.9

I must refresh the page (f5) to get it works!

Comment: You mean you are importing? If so, can we see the file?

Comment: No, I mean when I click on table structure link

Comment: Please open an issue on https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues. We already have another issue on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Same error on Windows 8.1 with MariaDB 10.1.9.

I solved using an older phpmyadmin version, in my case the 4.4.15.1

You can find it here: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/